# Laravel Project, only home view is working, other views giving 404 not found

Tags: laravel, centos

I have a laravel project for restaurants. Laravel version is 5.1, it's working on my localhost windows - xampp, and working fine on my hosting service + whm.

I installed a physical linux server on a hp xeon, centos 7.
I've installed apache, mysql, php, phpmyadmin and all is good the server is running well.

I copied my laravel project to /var/www/myproject.com and configured a virtual host for this project and the vhost is working fine, tested with a simple html page.

When I try to open the project, home page is opening but the other views giving 404 not found, even requests giving 404 not found so the home is loading without data only design.

I searched for this issue, tried to fix the .htaccess in public, allowoverrid all and all solutions, I fixed the document root in httpd conf.

Nothing is working.

**PS: When I uploaded my laravel project to the live server months ago (working project), I've renamed the server.php, and copied the index.php from public to the project root. I did that to access my project without adding /public to the url, maybe this is causing an issue here.**

Any help?

Comment: _maybe this is causing an issue here_: likely yes, you've "fixed" document root in httpd conf. Does it means you've pointed it to `public` directory?

Comment: yes document root is pointed to the public directory in my project

Comment: _renamed the server.php, and copied the index.php from public to the project root_ <-- revert everything back, then.

Comment: ok will give a try, another question how it's working on my hosting service ? and thanks for help )

Answer (score 4):

This is an error of apache rewrite. if you access your site using `index.php/your-url` it will work.

You need to put this in your virtual host config file

```
<Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi I have the same issue. But I couldn't add your lines to my VirtualHost config file. or I did it wrong. Could you please tell me be below is correct or how can I correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Apply permission as below : 
1) All files permission as 644
2) Apply all other folder permission as 755
3) Provide 777 permission on public folder and storage folder